# Що таке "шифа"?

Tags: значення-слів

Нещодавно відвідав презентацію дитячої книги "Небесні ноти". Авторка цієї книги вставила ноти (до, ре, мі тощо) в різні слова української мови, наприклад **мі**ст, во**до**йма тощо. І серед цих слів була "ши**фа**", але що це за слово і чи можна його взагалі вважати українським?

Раніше я такого не чув, тому вирішив пошукати в СУМі, однак там такого слова немає, а Гугл мені видав посилання на російське слово "[шифа](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/islam/905/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0)", яке запозичене з арабської та означає "сцілення від хвороби".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не знаю відки панї авторка, можу лиш припустити, шчо зі західної частини Украӥни, де був значниј вплив нїмецької, а тут сє [*Schiff*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schiff), тому окрім *шифа* зустрічаєть ся менш правильниј напис за звучнею — *шіфа*.

Наприклад Чернівцї мають [*будинок-корабель*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96)), котрого коротко звуть *шифою*.

Окрім згаданого, вважати украӥнським словом складно, оскільки *ф* — не є питомою буквою чи звуком.

Comment: Так казка про Чернiвцi i є. https://shpalta.media/tag/nebesni-noti/

Comment: [РОЗВИТОК ЛЕКСИКИ УКРАЇНСЬКИХ ГОВІРОК БУКОВИНИ В ХХ СТОЛІТТІ](http://library.chnu.edu.ua/res/library/elib/visnyk_chnu/visnyk_chnu_2008_0428_0429.pdf) На цьому тлі за останні 60 років спостерігається значна втрата слів, запозичених в часи Австрії з німецької мови. Перестали користуватися німецькими словами, якими позначалися різні військові реалії: <...> Побутова лексика, яка вийшла із вжитку: <...> 'Шіфа – корабель.Шіцу'вати – оцінювати майно. Ш'пацір – прогулянка.

Comment: Також Русинсько-український словник (вікісловник) https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA "шіфа — корабель".

Answer (score 2):

***Шiфа*** - русинською мовою "корабель", "човен".

http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/10/53416/118320.html
Шифа, можливо, орфографічний варіант.

(++)

В Чернiвцях саме так i пишуть: *Шифа - дом-корабель.*
Казка ця саме про Чернiвцi.

*ПС. Вказівки на всі помилки приймаю з вдячністю.*

Answer (score 2):

Приклади вживання слова *шіфа/шифа* в значенні «корабель»:

- [Іван Боберський, «Як перших двох українців заїхало до Канади, в р. 1891», 21 листопада 1936 р., Тржич, Югославія, Европа (Археографічний щорічник «Пам'ятки», 8’2008, с. 164–174)](https://undiasd.archives.gov.ua/doc/pamjatky/2008.pdf#page=174):

  > Продав я пару коней і воли, щоб мати гроші на **шифкарту**⁴, але виглядало, що не вистарчить на дорогу. <…> В Гамбурзі, куди нас двоє доїхало, був аґент, який посадив нас на велику **шифу**⁶, щоби ми їхали через море. <…> Рано злізли ми із **шифи**, а пополудни всіли на трен і поїхали впоперек Канади. <…> Тутки треба було чекати п’ять днів на **шифу**. <…> Я кажу: «Їхав до Кракова, відти до Берліна, відти до Гамбурґа. Потім їхав через море до Монтреалю, а звідси сів на колію до Виннипеґу. Я їхав залізницями і **шіфою**». <…> Відти дісталися ми **шифою** через море, а потім рікою до Квебеку²⁰. Відти заїхали ми треном²¹ до Виннипеґу.
  >
  > <sub>⁴ **Шіфкарта**, **шифкарта** (з нім. – die Schiffkarte) – картка або білет на корабель. <…>
  >
  > ⁶ **Шифа**, **шіфя** (з нім. – der Schiff) – корабель. <…>
  >
  > ²¹ «Трен» – (від англ. train) – поїзд.</sub>
- [Мочульський Іван, «Я і моє життя»](https://sites.google.com/a/vox-populi.com.ua/newspaper/rubriki/istoria/zlocini-nkvd/aimoezittaavtormoculskijivan-1):

  > Він сам виробляв «**шіфкарту**», документи на виїзд, давав аванс грошима. Коли «бос» набрав людей, всі разом від’їжджали. Проводи і прощання були повні сліз, бо їхали «**шіфою**» (так називали корабель) морем в далеку, незнану нам «Гамерику».
- Михайло Береза, «Героїна Марґарета де Робервал. (Переклад з Канадийської Істориї.)» (Франко І., «Батьківщина і инші оповідання», Едмонтон, 1919; [на Діаспоріані](https://diasporiana.org.ua/proza/19084-franko-i-batkivshhina-i-inshi-opovidannya/), [в Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/batkivshchynaiyn00fran); с 57–59):

  > Він не міг знести розлуки зі своєю любкою і тому він зголосив ся яко охотник їхати з Робервалом і поплив в тій самій **шіфі**, що він і єго братаниця. <…> Коли **шіфа** вертала перепливаючи знов попри сей заклятий остров, він викрав ся з припоясаною своєю стрільбою, скочив до моря і своєю зручностию приплив до розбитого серця Марґарети. <…> Через вісїмнайцять довгих, хмарних місяців, она блукала лісистими берегами і придивляла ся старанно на всхід, своїми від плачу висушеними очима, на широкий океан за **шіфою**. Три або чотири рази показували ся білі пасма **шіфи** на блакітнім овидї і скоро зникали, що ще більше збільшало єї горість ніж перед тим. Трета зима збилжала ся і одного дня она заздріла бажальну **шіфу**. Які старанні приготована она почала робити аби збижити **шішфу** к собі; до сего острашаючого берега, який уважав ся бути мешканєм чортів. Она клала всі свої сили аби доконати те бажане. Пожертвувала свій щупний засіб дерева, котрий крівавим потом громадила з лїса, запалила свою хатину, в надії, що зверне увагу чужинців. Близше і близше припливала **шіфа** риболовцїв.

Answer (score 1):

У [словнику малозрозумілих слів](https://nashe.com.ua/songbook/22/info/22) на НАШЕ (тексти пісень) маємо:

> дампшифа – пароплав
> шифа, шіфа – корабель
> шифкарта – квиток на пароплав

Також в [романі «Корнелія»](https://starylev.com.ua/news/nadiya-morykvas-korneliya-knyga-shcho-pochalasya-z-lyubovi) Надії Мориквас:

> Кава не родила, гроші на шифу, тобто квиток на пароплав, прислала дружина.

Answer (score -3):

Шифою у Галичині називали (називають) поїзд.

Comment: Дякуємо. А можете навести приклад такого вживання (наприклад: у книзі, на сайті абощо)?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.

Comment: Поставлю мінус. Не тому, що незгоден з відповіддю, а тому, що її дуже важко перевірити (всюди пишуть, що шифа — корабель, але ніде не бачу про поїзд). Якби Андро навів бодай якесь посилання…